# What is the best way to store user info in React Redux?

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am learning React Redux. I am having a very difficult time learning it. Please excuse how bad my code is because I only started learning a few days ago I want to have a store for the logged in user. It will contain their username, email, etc. **Currently I am not using sessions/cookies nor even a database for the users. I am simply trying to learn Redux.**

I need help with a few things. The state can contain many objects. I just want one object for the user. And because I am currently having trouble with that, how do I display the username without having to .map() because the state is an array?

Here is my current code for the actions/reducers.

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const defaultUser = [];

// Actions
const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";

export function loginUser(user) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_USER,
        user,
    };
}

// Reducers
function user(state = defaultUser, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    username: action.user,
                },
            ];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const usersStore = combineReducers({ user });

export default usersStore;
```

Here is the App.js file where I want a user to type a username in the input box, then print out their username.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import "./App.css";

import { Sidebar } from "./components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import { Content } from "./components/Content/Content";

import { loginUser } from "./store";

const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");

    const selectedUser = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(loginUser(user));
        setUser("");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                    value={user}
                />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
            <br />
            <br />
            {selectedUser.map((selectUser) => (
                <li key={selectUser.username}>
                    <h3>{selectUser.username}</h3>
                </li>
            ))}
            <Content />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own. With my new setup, all I have to do is type {user.username} to get the username of the logged in user. I am fetching it with useSelector().

It basically sets the username as a state temporarily, then sends it over to the store via dispatch, then empties out the state afterwards.

I had to change the initialstate to an object with "profile" inside it (instead of using an array)
I then had to map the state to props of the component I want it to display in, using a function, and then use connect() when exporting it.

Here's my new component code, the bottom few lines are the most important:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

import "./App.css";

import { Sidebar } from "./components/Sidebar/Sidebar";
import { Content } from "./components/Content/Content";

import { loginUser } from "./store";

const App = (props) => {
    const [stateUser, stateSetUser] = useState("");

    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.profile);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(loginUser(stateUser));
        stateSetUser("");
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    onChange={(e) => stateSetUser(e.target.value)}
                />
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </form>
            {user.username}
            <Content />
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        profile: state.user.profile,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

My reducer/actions file: (changes in initialstate are most important)

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const initialState = {
    profile: {
        username: "",
        email: "",
        profileImage: "",
    },
};

// Actions
const LOGIN_USER = "LOGIN_USER";

export function loginUser(user) {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_USER,
        user,
    };
}

// Reducers
function user(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                profile: { username: action.user },
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const usersStore = combineReducers({ user });
export default usersStore;
```